# Getting "not a valid internet calendar file" in Outlook when starting in IE, not other browsers

Tags: outlook

I am trying to subscribe to an internet calendar from Outlook 2010.  The web site contains a webcal link.  When I click on the link in Chrome or FF, i get the browser warning message, then the Outlook warning message, then Outlook creates the subscription without any issues.

However, when I click on the same webacal link in IE (IE9), I get both warnings, but when Outlook attempts to subscribe, I get the file is "not a valid internet calendar file" message.  If I copy the webcal link from IE and instead manually paste the internet calendar URL using File --> Info --> Acount Settings --> Internet Calendars, that works fine.

In other words, it works fine with every browser but IE.